# How to rotate X Labels in MATLAB R2014a using edit tool?

Tags: matlab

I have 18*17 matrix, for which I have plotted a pcolor map in matlab.
I have changed the xtick and ytick lables using edit tool in matlab.

Is it possible to change the orientation/angle of the lables (right now they are horizontally placed, I want them to be vertical) by using edit tool directly without writing any code?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible.

If you want to change the properties of your plot you need to assign your plot to a variable when you define it.
For example you write:
m1 = plot(x,y);

Then to access the Axes properties you need to call the parent of the object m1 (which is the parent of the plot object). To do that you can write:
a1 = m1.Parent;

The property of the horizontal axis (x-axis) label rotation is called "XTickLabelRotation". if you want to make your x axis vertical you should assign the value of 90 (degrees) to this property.

So you write:
a1.XTickLabelRotation = 90

Now your x-axis label is rotated by 90 degrees.

As an example run this code:

```
x = [1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10];
y = x.^2;
m1 = plot(x, y);
a1 = m1.Parent;
a1.XTickLabelRotation = 90
```